# Are questions about music videos on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

While music videos are not music, there are cases where:

- the video is tightly associated with the piece,
- fans need explanations about the video's meaning (with regards the meaning of the song)
- we are just interested about the history behind it.

Examples of such questions are:

- How is it that we have a music video for Pink Floyd's "Arnold Layne" since music videos were uncommon at that time?
- Who is the woman who appears at Chicago's "Stay the night" music video?
- What is the connection between video an lyrics in REM's "Losing my religion"?

I think there are many questions about music videos worth asking, but, because music video has so dominated the music industry, we should draw a line so that this site will not end up by being about music videos.

What do you think?

Comment: I don't understand how asking about the meaning of the video is more on topic than asking about the meaning of the song... As such the third example is bad IMO. The first example question is a very bad one as the answer is, "they made one"

Comment: 1st question is bad. However, anybody could be just curious about the "making of" any video. 3rd question, many videos -and songs as well- contain cultural references that remain unknown outside USA or UK. I guess 2nd question is OK? I thought that was a bad question :) To sum up, I just do not know where the red line should be drawn.

Answer (score 9):

I will say yes. Fans watch and talk about music videos.

We have a [music-videos](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music-videos) and two questions already:

- [What is considered to be the first music video?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/156/what-is-considered-to-be-the-first-music-video/159#159)
- [Why does the actor commit suicide at the end of the video to “You're Beautiful”?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/258/why-does-the-actor-commit-suicide-at-the-end-of-the-video-to-youre-beautiful)

Comment: This answer could use a good bit more description as to what types of questions regarding music videos is on or off topic

Answer (score 4):

I'd say yes. As you have mentioned, the music and video are tightly integrated. You can't have a music video with out the music, therefore I think it's valid to discuss. The only thing to be wary of is like all other on-topic questions, be wary of straying into music video questions that produce the list and opinion type answers.

Comment: This answer could use a good bit more description as to what types of questions regarding music videos is on or off topic

Comment: @ZachSaucier "List and opinion type" questions have been much discussed in other questions, there's no special application to music video questions.